# Lync 2013 SDK ActivityID for "In a conference call" and "In a meeting

Tags: lync, lync-2013, lync-client-sdk

The Lync 2013 SDK has some pretty non-intuitive ActivityID strings used as "identifiers" for the [built-in availabilities](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Change-your-presence-status-in-Skype-for-Business-Lync-ef8998cc-7801-4b62-81ba-9a2c1630f9e5?ui=en-US&rs=en-AU&ad=AU).

Here are the ones I have deciphered:

- Available - "Free"
- Busy - "Busy"
- In a call - "on-the-phone"
- In a meeting - ???
- In a conference call - ???
- Presenting - "in-presentation"
- Do not disturb - "DoNotDisturb"
- Be right back - "BeRightBack"
- Inactive - "Inactive"
- Away - "Away"
- Off work - "off-work"

I have been unable to discover the ActivityId for either "In a meeting" or "In a conference call" because they require Exchange Server and Office Web Apps Server, respectively, neither of which I have readily available to me at the moment.

Does anyone know what these two missing strings are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay. I decided to write a simple Lync SDK client that would allow me to try setting the Availability, and I was able to discover the missing IDs through trial-and-error. For posterity, they are:

- In a meeting - "in-a-meeting"
- In a conference call - "in-a-conference"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late but there is an MSDN article with the activity strings that you mentioned plus one more that does not appear in your overview: "urgent-interruptions-only"

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn454801#Anchor_0